# Is a Person an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, aggregate

Since all entities have a stamped of who created/modified the record, can we consider a Person entity an aggregate root to all entities?

That is, all entities that references the Person will become a collection to Person, e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderHeader> CreatedOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderHeader> ModifiedOrders { get; set; }

    // Other entities that have a reference on Person will be mapped as a collection under 
    // the Person entity
}


public class OrderHeader
{
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }        
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual string CommentsOnThisOrder { get; set; }

    // stamp audit-level concerns
    public virtual Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Person ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem 
{
    public virtual OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

That will basically make all entities become a collection to Person, which violates DDD aggregate root rules.

In my limited understanding of DDD aggregrate, the OrderHeader must not become a collection to Person, as we should not save the Order aggregate via Person. The only ***entry*** point for saving the Order aggregate(object graph) must be done from the OrderHeader, not from the Person.

Now here comes my real goal even why it looks dirty, I still wanted the Order to be a collection to Person:

There's one ORM *cough* NHibernate *cough* that cannot do a LEFT JOIN (.DefaultIfEmpty) from Person to OrderHeader if OrderHeader is not mapped as a collection to Person.  The only way to achieve LEFT JOIN from Person to OrderHeader is to map the OrderHeader as a collection to Person.

Should I allow infrastructure concerns (e.g. [facilitating](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/93a30501a8b72ce79a63455f0e44b28fb575733a) LEFT JOIN from Person to OrderHeader via Linq's .DefaultIfEmpty by making the OrderHeader become a collection to Person) break the rules on when should only an entity must become an aggregate root?

If we will not map the OrderHeader as a collection to Person, then if we needed to make a LEFT JOIN (flattened result, not hierarchical, hence the need to use LEFT JOIN) from Person to OrderHeader on NHibernate, the only option left is to use QueryOver. QueryOver is very tedious to write compared to Linq.

Cannot use the .DefaultIfEmpty(LEFT JOIN functionality) on NHibernate's Linq if we manually do a LEFT JOIN (i.e., via Linq's join and .DefaultIfEmpty) from Person to OrderHeader, .DefaultIfEmpty throws an exception if we do a manual LEFT JOIN on NHibernate, LEFT JOIN on NHibernate's Linq must be done via collection and .DefaultIfEmpty.

If done occasionally(per need-basis), is breaking the rules on aggregate root a pragmatic choice? Example, should I map the OrderHeader as collection to Person in order to facilitate LEFT JOIN from Person to OrderHeader via Linq?

**EDIT**

Sample northwind database. When we need to report all customers with their orders including those customers without orders(e.g., PARIS)

```
 CustomerID     OrderID
 OTTIK      |   10407
 OTTIK      |   10684
 OTTIK      |   10554
 PARIS      |        
 PERIC      |   10502
 PERIC      |   10474
 PERIC      |   10995
 PERIC      |   10354
 PERIC      |   11073
 PERIC      |   10322
```

, we need to do a LEFT JOIN:

```
select c.CustomerID, o.OrderID
from customers c
left join orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
order by c.CustomerID
```

That can be done with Linq's join and .DefaultIfEmpty(). However NHibernate's Linq can't do a .DefaultIfEmpty on the result of manual Linq join, it throws an exception. NHibernate's DefaultIfEmpty can only be applied on a collection. But I feel mapping a collection to something that is not an aggregate root violates DDD aggregate root rules. And also doing so, all entities such as Person (Customer is another example) will potentially contain collections of *ALL* entities, as every table has a CreatedByPerson reference.

@DanielSchilling:

I'm also surprised(in a good way), that referencing the OrderHeader from OrderItem violates DDD. Do we have some sort of whitepaper or a Martin Fowler article expounding on that? I thought referencing a parent entity from a child entity is not considered an infrastructure concern, thus considered DDD.

Comment: You mentioned to me in an edit that your goal is to export some data in an Excel spreadsheet or CSV file.  Could you add a brief example of the output you are shooting for?

Comment: @DanielSchilling That's the only example I cited for the rationale on flattening the result, by doing a LEFT JOIN manually, i.e., via Linq's join and .DefaultIfEmpty :-) Exporting to spreadsheet or CSV is not the only use case for doing manual join and .DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: Yes, but a specific use case is the only reason for ever doing anything at all.  You can't know "what you should do" without a definitive "why should you do it".  If there's no "why" - or if the reason is too ambiguous, the answer is "don't do it."

Comment: @DanielSchilling The example I gave on my question is already an specific use case. Cannot flip around the LEFT JOIN construct with the use case above, must start from CustomerID then down to their OrderHeaders. The only way I can do pure DDD on the Customer, i.e., not making Customer the aggregate's root while being able to produce reports like my edit above is to use NHibernate's QueryOver

Comment: :-) I think I'm just wanting to have a confirmatory bias if it's ok to violate DDD (making OrderHeader a collection to Customer) just for the need of doing a LEFT JOIN mechanism conveniently on NHibernate's Linq. QueryOver's LEFT JOIN mechanism is too convoluted and needlessly complicated compared to Linq. NHibernate's QueryOver can make a LEFT JOIN manually, i.e., even without mapping a collection, but its approach is too horrible and too tedious, I'm not ready to embrace NHibernate's QueryOver yet just for adhering to DDD properly :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Thoughts on DDD decisions...

It sounds like you want to be able to do this:

```
var people = session.Query<Person>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.CreatedOrders)
    .Where(x => x.Id == personId);
```

You should just flip the query around, like so...

```
var orders = session.Query<OrderHeader>()
    .Fetch(x => x.CreatedBy)
    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy.Id == personId);
```

There's more reasons than just DDD purity to keep `person.CreatedOrders` out of your model.  What if you have one person that places 10 orders a day, every day of the year, year after year?  The first query almost certainly loads more data than you actually need. The second query, the one that doesn't need a `person.CreatedOrders` collection at all, gives you more control over which orders to fetch and how many to fetch.

```
var orders = session.Query<OrderHeader>()
    .Fetch(x => x.CreatedBy)
    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy.Id == personId)
    .Where(x => x.OrderDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
    .Skip(100)
    .Take(50);
```

Generally, if you find you're violating a DDD principle, it's usually a good indicator that you're doing something wrong, and you usually don't have to look too far to find other supporting evidence.

Every once in a while, though, you do have to bend the rules a bit, and I think that's acceptable.  For example, I usually try to just map one side of each relationship - that's all I really need from a DDD perspective.  When referencing other aggregate roots, that usually means just modeling the `many-to-one` side, and for references within an aggregrate root - from the root to its children, that usually means just modeling the `one-to-many` and leaving the `many-to-one` out of the model.  That would mean leaving `OrderItem.OrderHeader` out of the model.

What if you needed to find out how much of a particular product had been sold, but only for Orders that have been Submitted?  The easiest way to do this would be like so:

```
var quantitySold = session.Query<OrderItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Product.Id == productId && x.OrderHeader.Submitted)
    .Sum(x => x.Quantity);
```

So in this case, we need to model both the `one-to-many` `orderHeader.OrderItems` and also the `many-to-one` `orderItem.OrderHeader`.  This is because it is most efficient for this SUM to access the relevant OrderItems directly, rather than first go through `OrderHeader` as DDD would dictate.  I'm OK with that.

#### Left outer joins on un-mapped relationships

Ignoring the DDD part of the question, this LEFT OUTER JOIN can be simulated by combining the results of two separate queries - one to get the orders...

```
var orders = session.Query<OrderHeader>()
    .Fetch(x => x.CreatedBy);
```

... and another to get the people that have no orders:

```
var peopleWithNoOrders = session.Query<Person>()
    .Where(p => !session.Query<OrderHeader>().Any(o => o.CreatedBy == p));
```

Comment: @Hao, in response to your "I'm also surprised(in a good way), that referencing the OrderHeader from OrderItem violates DDD". Eric Evans is actually the authority on DDD (if there is an authority) - and I actually have not read his book. It's on my to-do list. The reason I say that modeling only one side of the relationship is better from a DDD perspective - it makes it absolutely clear which entity is in charge of the relationship. There's no possibility for ambiguity.

Comment: If you map both sides of the relationship, then the `many-to-one` side, the child's reference to the parent, actually becomes the one in charge.  Mapping just one side, when possible, more accurately represents the relationship.  And generally you'll also find it's all you need.  It also *forces* you to identify the aggregate roots and treat them as such, because for each relationship you have to decide "should I map the many-to-one or the one-to-many?" - this choice is determined primarily by which things are aggregate roots.

Comment: I've added something about the LEFT OUTER JOIN part of the question to my answer.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person` may be an aggregate and your `Order` may b an aggregate.  One aggregate root instance should not reference an instance of another.  Try not to think in terms of ORM or database.

I can point you to these answers (they may be relevant):

[How to avoid holding reference to non-root-aggregate in another non-root-aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920521/how-to-avoid-holding-reference-to-non-root-aggregate-in-another-non-root-aggrega/16931585#16931585)

[DDD: one-to-many relationship between user aggregate root and almost all entities in other aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378688/ddd-one-to-many-relationship-between-user-aggregate-root-and-almost-all-entitie/16386858#16386858)